# Css Selectors: Select id or class with a random part in the middle

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a template, which will be duplicated for the use.
and the css rules I have created are in some cases specific for the template only, because the cms creates a random ID number and adds it in the middle of IDs / classes.

So I was wondering how to select them...

The structure would be like this:

```
 <div id="row-123456-StaticPart"> content </div>
```

Whereas here '123456' would be the random generated ID for the page. So if I duplicate the template, on the next page it would be '654321' for example:

```
 <div id="row-654321-StaticPart"> content </div>
```

How can I write a rule to select both these ID's? (except for changing the number manually)

I'm thinking of something like:

```
#row-*-Staticpart {
    color: red;
}

or
div[id|="row-*-Staticpart"] {
    color: red;
}
```

Thanks for any ideas in advance!

Comment: you can generate a class for both elements

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use CSS 3 selectors :

```
div[id^="row-"][id$="-StaticPart"]{
    color: red;
}
```

- `div[id^="row-"]` Selects every `<div>` element whose id attribute value begins with "row-"
- `div[id$="-StaticPart"]` Selects every `<div>` element whose id attribute value ends with "-StaticPart"

Comment: Be careful with the case: Staticpart vs StaticPart

Answer (score 4):

You can use css3 selectors like that:

```
div[id^="row-"][id$="-Staticpart"] {
    color: red;
}
```

the ^= indicates what the id should start with, and the $= indicates what it should ends with.

Comment: Thanks. Just tested it and it works like a charm. I must have looked only at css selectors, because i didn't see any of these...will check out css3. Thanks also for the additional explanation of what the ^ and $ mean...